# Restarting a user thread conditionally in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I know that I can stop a thread conditionally in JMeter.

In my script I'm sending a requests and then I'm extracting their response json to further process it. There are some rare cases, where the parameter response provides some value that I cannot process in further steps.

I could actually detect this valid response by extracting another parameter. Would it be possible to just restart the thread based on condition, instead of stopping it?

Comment: Even if you *can* you *may* get infinite loop, why you need to restart?

Comment: I was uploading file that would get converted next, and then I was just waiting with next upload request until previous file gets converted (in order not to stack the conversion processes to queue). Getting wrong response and passing its value further caused wrong data being extracted into the next request, which was causing the script loop. Anyway I've managed to restart the script though, I'll post the solution for this kind of work, so it might be useful for someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For further researchers:

The easy way to start another iteration of a thread based on condition (i.e extracting some data out of json) is to use a BeanShell Sampler in way like described above.

```
    import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;
    import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContext;
    import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContext.TestLogicalAction;


    String statVar = vars.get("statusVariable");    //getting some data for condition check (statusVariable is a variable that has been set previously in the Jmeter JSON Extractor)

    if(statVar.equals("NOK")){ .                   //checking the condition

    SampleResult.setTestLogicalAction(TestLogicalAction.START_NEXT_ITERATION_OF_THRE 
            AD);                                  //Starting thread again (it starts the thread from the beginning, so we may compare this to restart effect)
}
```

Comment: Next iteration isn't equal to restart

Comment: You're right it's more like moving to another iteration in terms of skipping current thread.

Comment: i want to use the code in JSR223 groovy, but surprisingly for me I could not make it work there. Do you have a complete working groovy code?

Answer (score 2):

Without scripting, you can add [Flow Control Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) (was: Test Action )

Choose Target: `Current Thread` and Action: `Start Next Thread Loop`

It'll skip "damaged" thread and continue to the next thread