# Jmeter loop again if at least one request fails

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223

I am using Jmeter to fill a database with data, which I will later user for performance testing.

The problem is I get sometimes a random error, 100 entry or 5000th entry which stops my thread and data entry until I did the necessary to start the dataload again. I think a simple retry loop should solve this manual restart.

My Jmeter structure is as follows:

```
Threadgroup
-Start Dummy sampler
-- Loop Controller
--- Counter
--- Dummy Sampler
--- User Parameter: Variable "Error" = null
--- While Controller: ${__javaScript("${Error}"!="false",)}
---- Transaction Controller
----- User Parameter: Variable "Error" = false
----- Dummy Sampler 1
----- Dummy Sampler 2 (build in fail/success)
----- Dummy Sampler 3
----- Dummy Sampler 4
----- JSR223 postprocessor
-- Assertion
```

What I would like to achieve is that if an assertion fails for whatever reason on whatever sample/request, the while loop should restarted. Basically in case of a failure, retry loop with same data.

I tried it with many variation of the examples below in Groovy and JavaScript, but couldn't get it to work.
I think my problem is in the comparison.

```
if(vars.get("JMeterThread.last_sample_ok").equals('false')){vars.put("Error","true");}
if(vars.get("JMeterThread.last_sample_ok")=='false'){vars.put("Error","true");}
```

Does someone see the issue? Or could suggest an alternative solution to my problem?
I do now want to start a new thread via the threadgroup control, as I want to retry with my current data/variables until success before going to the next dataset (csv)

---

Solution:
I added a JSR223 Listener at the threadgroup level with the following code:

```
if(vars.get("JMeterThread.last_sample_ok")=="false"){vars.put("Error","true");}
```

Although when looking through the debug sampler, it doesn't seem to update the variable, it still works and does what I want.

I also looked at the Result Status Action Handler, however it doesn't really work. It only works at the sampler level, so I would have to add the element to each sampler... I will look into this and try to work around it via additional code in the JSR223 Listener.

Comment: Did you try using the ctx.setRestartNextLoop(true) in old versions OR 
ctx.setStartNextThreadLoop(true) in the new versions. Also, the new version of JMeter has other advanced features to control your test flow. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53371798/restarting-a-user-thread-conditionally-in-jmeter

Comment: I have not tried that yet. But as far as I understand, this will start a completely new thread, where I want to use the same thread, inside my current loop and restart this specific loop.

Comment: I agree. That's why, I asked it as a question here. As far as I know, there is no option to achieve this without duplicating the logic across.