# Jmeter-Start a specific request after error and the subsequent requests

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, beanshell, jmeter-5.0

I have a scenario which has 10 transactions and say 50 requests. I have to handle a situation if any request gets fail in any of the transaction controllers, it should go back to say Request-3 and then the subsequent requests.

Below is the screenshot for reference:
Here we have 4 transactions,now if transaction-2(Archives) gets fail, it should go back to execute homepage and then again archives and so on. The issue is I can not just give flow control action in one sampler as the case is "**If any request gets failed it should go back to homepage**".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2a8Va.png)

I tried solution given in [Jmeter loop again if at least one request fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55067471/jmeter-loop-again-if-at-least-one-request-fails) but I want to start the loop for same thread.

Please suggest a solution which can be applied in once for all the requests.

Answer (score 0):

From your description it's not very clear what you're trying to achieve so I'll give you 2 options:

1. Use [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler which have various behaviors, i.e. "Go to next iteration of Current Loop" seems suitable

   [image]
2. Put all your "transactions" into [Test Fragments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) and use [Module Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller) for referencing these fragments, this way you can build arbitrary flow, see [Easily Write a GOTO Statement in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/easily-write-a-goto-statement-in-jmeter) article for more details.

The "failed" request/transaction can be caught by [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) and `${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok }` [pre-defined variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars)

Comment: please check my edited post. I have tried the solutions but they didn't work