# JMeter setTestLogicalAction from JMeterContext gives "Cannot reach instance method"

Tags: java, groovy, jmeter

JMeter 5.1. The following link gives a working code [Restarting a user thread conditionally in JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53371798/restarting-a-user-thread-conditionally-in-jmeter) where `setTestLogicalAction` is called from `SampleResult`. the method is indeed listed in methods in https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html.
However, it's also listed in https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html but using `org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContext.setTestLogicalAction` gives

```
ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``    import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;     import org.apache.jmeter . . . '' : Cannot reach instance method: setTestLogicalAction( org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContext$TestLogicalAction ) from static context: org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContext
```

Why can't I use `setTestLogicalAction` from `JMeterContext`? What do I miss about classes in java?

Also, the code from above mentioned post works in beanshell, but neither that nor modified as above code works in JSR223+Groovy. After taking notice that methods are not static, code is as below (both paths were tried, finally I list them together) in groovy, no errors, but thread continues, not restarted...

```
jmco = new org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContext();
jmsr = new org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult();

jmco.setTestLogicalAction(org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContext.TestLogicalAction.START_NEXT_ITERATION_OF_THREAD);                                 
jmsr.setTestLogicalAction(org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContext.TestLogicalAction.START_NEXT_ITERATION_OF_THREAD);
```

Can I use `setTestLogicalAction` in groovy script?

P.S. interesting how beanshell can call non-static method w/o instantiation ...

ADDED 2019/04/01:

```
def mycontext = org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getContext()
mycontext.setTestLogicalAction(org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContext.TestLogicalAction.START_NEXT_ITERATION_OF_THREAD);
```

the code was changed to the above after suggestion in Dmitri answer, but the code does not restart the thread.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you're not that good at programming go for [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler instead of trying to replicate its functionality in code, in any case it will be faster.
2. There is no need to instantiate neither JMeterContext nor SampleResult as they're [pre-defined in JSR223 Test Elements](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy), moreover you're doing this wrong, i.e. correct way of accessing JMeterContext is calling [JMeterContextService.getContext() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContextService.html#getContext--)

   [image]
3. [Since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so I would recommend forgetting about Beanshell.

Comment: thanx, I added to the question the changed code with getContext() but the result is not achieved. `SampleResult.setTestLogicalAction(org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContext.TestLogicalAction.START_NEXT_ITERATION_OF_THREAD);` produces error. Is restarting thread by code so complex to push to using extra test plan element?

Comment: I want to restart thread conditionally, so to use flow element I would need to set variable and then use if controller + flow controller, IMHO should be easier to restart directly in groovy code.

Answer (score 1):

`prev.setTestLogicalAction(org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContext.TestLogicalAction.START_NEXT_ITERATION_OF_CURRENT_LOOP)`

worked for me (from a Groovy based post processor).